# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated - ошибка при запуске quasar

Tags: vue.js, модули, quasar.js

при запуске quasar dev сервер запускается, а в браузере: "не удается получить доступ к сайту" и warning в консоли "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."

Пробовал в настройках сети выбрать "без ограничений" и перезапустить приложение - не помогло.

Quasar установил глобально.

Так же пробовал запускать через npx и с различными настройками проекта.

Comment: UPD. проблема заключается в 9000 порту.

На 9001 проект разворачивается.

Почему? Пока не понял.

Убиваю процессы на порту с помощью команды npx kill-port 9000
Процесс убивается, но ошибка не уходит